# Prove that $\int_0^1 \psi{(x) \sin(2 n \pi x)} \space\mathrm{dx}=-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, special-functions, definite-integrals

Prove that
$$\int_0^1 \psi{(x) \sin(2 n \pi x)} \space\mathrm{dx}=-\frac{\pi}{2}, \space n\ge1$$
where $\psi(x)$ - digamma function

Comment: What is $\psi(x)$?

Comment: The claim is clearly wrong for $n=0$.

Comment: An interesting commentary for the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the log-differentiation of the Euler's reflection formula, we have

$$ \psi_0(x) - \psi_0(1-x) = -\pi \cot (\pi x). $$

Thus we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\psi_0(x) \sin (2\pi n x) \, dx
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\psi_0(x) \sin (2\pi n x) \, dx - \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\psi_0(1-x) \sin (2\pi n x) \, dx \\
&= -\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin (2\pi n x)}{\sin (\pi x)} \, \cos (\pi x) \, dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin (2 n \theta)}{\sin \theta} \, \cos \theta \, d\theta \\
&= - \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin (2 n \theta)}{\sin \theta} \, \cos \theta \, d\theta.
\end{align*}

Now the rest follows by [my blog posting](http://sos440.tistory.com/207).

Comment: @Chris'ssister, thank you. :)

Comment: @sos440 By the way, cool blog you have out there.

Comment: @sos440: I like your use of the reflection formula. (+1)

Answer (score 6):

Here's another approach using the integral representation for $\psi$.
We assume $n$ is an integer greater than or equal to one. 
Then 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 dx\, \sin(2n\pi x)  \psi(x)
&=& \int_0^1 dx\, \sin(2n\pi x) 
\int_0^\infty dt\, 
\left(
\frac{e^{-t}}{t} - \frac{e^{-x t}}{1-e^{-t}}
\right) \\
&=& \int_0^\infty dt\,
\left(
\frac{e^{-t}}{t} \int_0^1 dx\, \sin(2n\pi x)
- \frac{1}{1-e^{-t}} \int_0^1 dx\, \sin(2n\pi x)e^{-x t}
\right).
\end{eqnarray*}$$
But $\int_0^1 dx\, \sin(2n\pi x) = 0$ and 
$$\int_0^1 dx\, \sin(2n\pi x)e^{-x t} = \frac{2n\pi}{t^2+4n^2\pi^2}(1-e^{-t}).$$
(Details for the second integral can be given if necessary.)
Therefore 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 dx\, \sin(2n\pi x)  \psi(x)
&=& -\int_0^\infty dt\, \frac{2n\pi}{t^2+4n^2\pi^2} \\
&=& -\frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: ${(\text{precious})}^{\text{precious}}$ (+1) :-) Your way is very short and easy. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Glad to help. I had not seen this interesting integral before. (+1)